# Adjusting Rowheader properties on Datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

In Winforms DataGridView, how do I:

1. Remove the arrow on the row header? I need to display the row header text, so I can't simply set `RowHeadersVisible = false`.
2. Adjust the width of the row header programmatically? I'm setting the row headers by code so I need the width to adjust to show the row header text upon change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all override the function the DataGridView known as

```
private void dataGridView1_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.PaintHeader(DataGridViewPaintParts.All & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentBackground);
}
```

On button click add value to row header

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = "khan yousafzai";
    dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth +(7* a.Length);
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Value = a;
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you need to still allow sorting but not show the arrow? 
   If not, just set each column `SortMode` to `NotSortable`.
   If you need to sort but not show the arrow, set the column `SortMode` to `Programmatic`, and manually sort the data source in the column `Click` or `MouseDown` event.
2. After you set the column header to whatever text you need, get the width of the text using the form `Graphics` class and then set the column width accordingly:

   ```
   Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
   int w = (int)g.MeasureString(dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText, dataGridView1.Font).Width;
   this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = w;
   ```

Comment: Uhh.. neither solution didn't work. I need the rowheader width to be adjusted programmatically, not the first column

Comment: You sure you mean the row header, not column header? The row header is the blank boxes to the left of the grid and contains no text.

Comment: I am absolutely positive. I've programmatically set their text in my code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, how to add number line RowHeadersWidth to DataGridView in C# .Net 2.0 and above:

```
// On Form_Load add the numeration to DataGridView Row Header
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = (i + 1).ToString();
}
```

Now, you can resize our row header dynamically depending of its size, just like in Microsoft Excel.

```
// Dinamically adjust row header size to max current width available (like Microsoft Excel does)
private void dataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    int firstDisplayedCellIndex = dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell.RowIndex;
    int lastDisplayedCellIndex = firstDisplayedCellIndex + dataGridView1.DisplayedRowCount(true);
    
    Graphics Graphics = dataGridView1.CreateGraphics();
    int measureFirstDisplayed = (int)(Graphics.MeasureString(firstDisplayedCellIndex.ToString(), dataGridView1.Font).Width);
    int measureLastDisplayed = (int)(Graphics.MeasureString(lastDisplayedCellIndex.ToString(), dataGridView1.Font).Width);
                
    int rowHeaderWitdh = System.Math.Max(measureFirstDisplayed, measureLastDisplayed);
    dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = rowHeaderWitdh + 35;
}
```

This solution its only for .Net Framework 2.0 and above, not for CF.