# Visual Studio: C# GridView - column header inline with row

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, gridview

I can't figure how to do this as I'm using GridView in Visual Studio 2012:

GridView by default is:

```
-------------------------
| Column 1  | Column 2 |
-------------------------
| Data 1    | Data 2    |
-------------------------
```

Basically header ("Column 1") is on top I want to get the following view:

```
-------------------------
| Column 1 | Data 1    |
-------------------------
| Column 2 | Data 2    |
-------------------------
```

I can't find an option in the GridView properties to do this. Is there a workaround or should I just use Form View ?

Comment: Why not using RowHeader instead?

Comment: How do i set it to RowHeader i cant find this under properties.

Comment: You'll have to make 1 column (add it in the properties of the GridView) and then in each row's header property change Name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188788/adjusting-rowheader-properties-on-datagridview. If your data spreads horizontally you'll have to add columns dynamically of course :)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132829/wpf-horizontal-datagrid . It restyles and rotates it 90 degrees.

Comment: go for datalist or repeater control and achieve it with custom CSS

Comment: @Lukiahas - I believe he's not using wpf